# How would you fill in this relatively consistent pattern, but mimic/interpolate unique details like these darker spots?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image]

I attempted messing around with clonestamping and content-aware scaling but I couldn't quite make it as seamless as I would like it. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Honestly, I'd simply [find](https://www.google.com/search?q=kraft+paper+texture&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjr0JTpsaH1AhVJCs0KHQbhAwEQ_AUoAXoECBQQAw&biw=1747&bih=1137&dpr=1.1) a more suitable image.

Answer (score 0):

Normally  for something like this you could use *Edit > Content-Aware Fill* and afterwards use *Stamp Tool* and *Spot Healing Brush Tool* to clean things up a bit.

The problem here is that you don't really have much texture to begin with. The color isn't even and large parts of the border is very blurred or out of focus.

If I just make a selection around the white square and apply *Edit > Content-Aware Fill* using the default settings, the differentiating colors of the border blend in an unpleasing way:

[image]

If instead I tick on *Mirror*, the result looks a little better:

[image]

You *could* use *Stamp Tool* and *Spot Healing Brush* to even this out and add some more black spots (which Photoshop seem to ignore when filling), but the image is heavily affected by the blurred parts of your pattern. The result ends up being a collage of sharp and blurry parts:

[image]

As a last attempt, I try making a selection covering *both* the white square *and* the unwanted blurry parts. Now Photoshop has too little information and the texture have noticeable repeated areas.

[image]

Perhaps you could make use of this method if you manipulated the image both before and after the content-aware filling, but it would be a lot easier and probably look a lot better if you simply scanned a piece of paper or cardboard which has a texture you like.